# Check form errors in Django testing

Tags: django, testing, error-handling, field

I want to test field errors using `assertFormError`. How can I test it?

In forms.py

```
    password = forms.RegexField(max_length=254,
                                 error_messages={'required': _('This is required.') 
                                                'invalid': _('It is invalid)}
                                )
```

In tests.py

```
    form = UserForm(data=data)
    self.assertContains(form['password'].errors, 'It is invalid')
```

Comment: [docs for assertFormError](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertFormError)

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way you can test it. Note that you need to call the `is_valid` function:

```
self.assertFalse(form.is_valid())
self.assertEqual(form.errors['password'][0], 'It is invalid')
```

Comment: The real message is long more than 25 characters. Would assertContains work in this case? assertContains(form.errors['password'][0], ' xxx') raises AttributeError: str has no status code.

Comment: No, it wouldn't. `assertContains` is used to test whether a response contains certain text. You would use this when testing your views, not for testing forms.  Read more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertContains).

Comment: @Gene9y does this answer your question?

Comment: In that case, it works but as I said that the text is very long so I cannot adapt it. Anyway, thx.

Comment: @Gene9y Maybe I can still help. Are you saying that the error message you want to test is too long? How long is it? The `assertEqual` above should be able to handle a very long message.

Comment: It might be but it doesn't look that nice, so I am still looking further for a simpler way..

Comment: I see. This is the simplest way I know. If you find anything simpler, please post the answer here. I am interested to see.

Answer (score 3):

first you need to call is_valid method and then chceck if errors list has specific error like:

```
self.assertFalse(form.is_valid())
self.assertIn('password', form.errors.keys())
self.assertIn('It is invalid', form.errors['password'])
```

Comment: while testing (at least in Pytest which I am sure is the same in Unit tests) you can call/assess `form.errors` prior to checking `form.is_valid`

Comment: Thanks ! Just a small error though, last line should be `self.assertIn('It is invalid', form.errors['password'][0])`